# Выполнение асинхронной операции в конструкторе класса без контроля над созданием объекта

Tags: c#, async-await, quartz, deadlock

Есть кастомный quartz background worker, его настройки задаются из базы данных. Появилась необходимость удалять эти настройки на стадии инстанцирования объекта. Отсюда вытекает следующая проблема: мне необходимо вызвать асинхронную операцию в конструкторе. У меня нет доступа к инстанцированию объекта, он инстанцируется DI и вызывается где-то там, где у меня нет доступа.

Из-за этого я **вынужден** использовать очень плохую практику, которая приводит (и привела) к дедлоку, сам конструктор:

```
public MyBackgroundJobWorker(IQuartzRepository quartzRepository)
{
   quartzRepository.DeletePlanAsync(nameof(MyBackgroundJobWorker)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

У меня была попытка решить эту проблему следующим образом:

1. Добавить `Task.Run` - не помогло, дедлок так же остался, так теперь еще и в брейкпоинт внутрь `DeletePlanAsync` не заходит
2. Попытаться сделать метод синхронным - не смог, получение нужного мне `DbContext` происходит асинхронно.

Тело метода `DeletePlanAsync`:

```
public async Task<bool> DeletePlanAsync(string jobName)
{
   //после вызова этого метода код уйдет в дедлок
   bool triggerDeleted = await _triggerRepository.DeleteAsync(jobName);
   bool jobDetailsDeleted = await _triggerRepository.DeleteAsync(jobName);
   return triggerDeleted && jobDetailsDeleted;
}
```

Почему понадобилось удалять настройки: никак кроме как полным удалением настроек нельзя остановить воркер, потому что запускается она единожды при инстанцировании и работает пока программы не закроют. Руками я управлять жизненным циклом не могу и соответственно руками так же вызвать метод `Stop` я никак не могу. Quartz.NET хранит настройки для воркера (след. время выполнения, данные в виде byte[] итд..) в базе, поэтому это единственный вариант. Логика такая: нет настроек - нет воркера.

Comment: Побольше опишите это `Появилась необходимость удалять эти настройки на стадии инстанцирования объекта.` - что, как почему. Т.к. сейчас ваш вопрос выглядит как XY проблема. У вас объект сингтон? Есть разница, когда он именно инстанцируется? Почему асинхронный вызов нельзя выполнить где то в корне композиции или в каком то Setup методе? Если надо привести в порядок БД, почему это нельзя где то в методах контекста сделать? и тд

Comment: @tym32167 обновил вопрос, описал в самом конце

Comment: @tym32167 да, синглтон. "Почему асинхронный вызов нельзя выполнить где-то в корне композиции" - потому что мне удалять записи нужно только если в конфигурации в файле стоит `true`, я не могу залезть в контекст и вытащить там конфигурацию. По поводу методов setup - попробую

Comment: У меня нет опыта с quartz, но удаление внутренних данных воркера не выглядит хорошей идеей. Что делает этот воркер и почему его надо останавливать?

Comment: @tym32167 код в дедлок уходит на моменте await вызова внутри метода `DeletePlanAsync`

Comment: Если вы вызываете код из потока с контекстом синхронизации, то не удивительно, что он уходит в дедлок

Comment: Но вообще, как я написал, возможно есть более изящное решение вашей проблемы

Comment: У вас проект wpf? asp.net? И там и там есть всякие setup методы где можно и синглтоны создавать и инициализировать их асинхронным способом

Comment: @tym32167 этот воркер запускается 1 раз. У него есть триггеры которые вызывают n раз метод Execute с какими-то конкретными настройками. Некоторые вызовы Execute могут не понадобится и их надо отключить (т.е просто удалить из БД). Проект asp.net core. Удаление где-то в методе setup - я размазываю логику по коду который не относится к воркеру

Comment: Никаких размазываний. Воркер же ваш класс? Сделайте ему метод init асинхронный и вызывайте его в сетапе

Comment: @tym32167 нет возможности лично ему выделить какой-то setup метод. Есть только 1 метод OnApplicationInitialization()

Comment: М-м-м... Конфигурация всех объектов при использовании DI должна задаваться в Configuration Root. Сервисы при этом должны получать уже готовые объекты. | Если пишется сервис/библиотека, которая принимает зависимости извне, то достаточно просто затребовать эту нужную зависимость. А задать её конфигурацию должен тот, кто пишет Composition Root. Автора сервиса не волнует, как это будет сделано.

Comment: А если `quartzRepository.DeletePlanAsync(nameof(MyBackgroundJobWorker)).Wait()`?

Comment: @KirillHorn Wait/Result/GetAwaiter().GetResult одинаково приводят к блокировкам, там лишь пара ньюансов работы самих методов

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне нужен не сервис, а вызов метода, который удалит из БД нужную мне запись

Comment: `MyBackgroundJobWorker` создаётся с помощью DI-контейнера? / Убрать его прямое создание, сделать фабрику. Фабрику внедрить в DI.

Comment: [тыц](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). Оборачивание в `Task.Run` должно гарантированно помочь от дедлоков.

Comment: Почему бы не удалить из базы лишнее внутри самой базы?

Comment: @aepot потому что на это влияет свойство `IsActive` которое берется из appsettings, если isActive = false, то удаляем. В бд я не смогу постучаться к файлу